# How to create html select options where options are in another file and which type of file will be recommended

Tags: javascript, html, json

how to read Html select options from JSON file

Comment: Answer: A database

Comment: Could be a JSON file as you have tagged JSON, thats just a text file, nothing special there

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you already have those two files and are you able to load the "options" file? Any errors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could put these options in a json file if you don't use a database then read the file with JS while the page is loading

Comment: thank you I found the solution by putting them in a json file